# Font size changes in fullscreen on mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, font-size

While making one of my web apps responsive, I came across a very strange problem. **The font size of an element changes very drastically on toggling fullscreen. I found this problem in both Chrome DevTools emulation and Chrome on a real mobile.**

The following screenshots show what the problem is. Note that parts of the screenshot where censored for privacy but *all the important parts are shown.* (Windowed mode vs Fullscreen mode)
[image: Screenshot in windowed mode]
[image: Screenshot in fullscreen]

All the CSS applied to those elements is the following. As you can see no CSS has changed between both the modes. Then **why does this happen and how can I stop it?**
I have also looked at the Computed Styles, and it remains the same too. The computed style is 16px for both windowed and fullscreen mode i.e. relative units are not messing up.

```css
#a11y-controls button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
body.a11y button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px inset #4c9aff;
    outline: none;
}
button:focus {
    border-color: white;
}
button:hover {
    background: #555;
}
button {
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 80%;
    background: #000;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px;
}
user agent stylesheet
button {
    appearance: button;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: -internal-light-dark(black, white);
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(239, 239, 239), rgb(59, 59, 59));
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
@media (pointer: coarse)
#a11y-controls {
    height: 100px;
    bottom: -100px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
Style Attribute {
    pointer-events: all;
}
body {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: relative;
}
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color-scheme: dark light!important;
    font-family: 'Lato', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

and in fullscreen,

```css
#a11y-controls button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
body.a11y button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px inset #4c9aff;
    outline: none;
}
button:focus {
    border-color: white;
}
button:hover {
    background: #555;
}
button {
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 80%;
    background: #000;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px;
}
user agent stylesheet
button {
    appearance: button;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: -internal-light-dark(black, white);
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(239, 239, 239), rgb(59, 59, 59));
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
@media (pointer: coarse)
#a11y-controls {
    height: 100px;
    bottom: -100px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
Style Attribute {
    pointer-events: all;
}
body {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: relative;
}
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color-scheme: dark light!important;
    font-family: 'Lato', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

For your satisfaction, this is all the javascript used to handle the toggling of fullscreen mode.

```js
function toggleShotMode() {
    if (document.fullscreenElement === null) {
        //!titleInShot.checked ? picTitle.style.opacity = 0 : picTitle.style.opacity = 1;
        document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else {
        //picTitle.style.opacity = 1;
        document.exitFullscreen();
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML, censored but important parts are shown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">
    <link rel="stylesheet preload prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" as="style">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.webmanifest">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./apple-touch-icon.png">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="a11y-controls">
        <button id="a11y-prev-pic">Previous Picture</button>
        <button id="a11y-shot-moder">Toggle "Shot-Mode"</button>
        <button id="a11y-settings-toggler">Open/Close Settings</button>
        <button id="a11y-next-pic">Next Picture</button>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:* After some classic trial and error, the conclusion has finally emerged.

The culprit here was a missing [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

**Basic example:**
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Without specification, the browser was trying its best to render the larger desktop view on a mobile screen and unintentionally ignoring the mobile CSS.

Comment: Relative units are not messing up, see the updated question.

Comment: I even tried removing `font-size: 80%` but it didn't work.

Comment: Can I ask why `user agent stylesheet ` is included in your CSS? These are default styles provided by Google Chrome when you have not included your own styles. - You didn't include your HTML but can you make sure that `<!DOCTYPE>` is included in your HTML document?

Comment: For the answerer's satisfaction, I also included the styles the browser was applying but labeled them with `user agent stylesheet`. 
Yes, I have included the preamble. The HTML has not much and I do not think it is causing the problem but I have included it in the updated answer.

Comment: I figured it out, I missed adding the viewport `meta` tag, thanks for reminding me to check my HTML. If you update the answer with the solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! Those meta tags are troublemakers. I went ahead and updated the answer.